# Permanently redirect any url whether https or http to specific https url for which ssl certificate applies with apache

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to redirect various urls which resolve to the same webserver to on domain for which I have the ssl certificate. My apache conf has the following rewrite rules:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   !^(https?://(www\.)?)?my\.domain\.org [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS_HOST}   !^(https?://(www\.)?)?my\.domain\.org [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://my.domain.org$1 [R=301,L]
```

And then follows the Virtual host

```
 <VirtualHost *:443>
   ...
 </VirtualHost>
```

The above rules work for http://example.org to https://my.domain.org. They also work for http://my.domain.org to https://my.domain.org. They don't work for but not for https://example.org to https://my.domain.org. The browser gives the warning page for the certificate not matching the host. Any thoughts what's going wrong in my conditions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Likely not the rewrite rule - but the (bare or SNI) virtualhost and certificate pair you have setup. I.e. the value for the hostname(s) hardcoded into the certificate for those vhost(s).

One would expect the certificate of that server to be issued to *.example.org and have a subject alternative name of example.org.

You can check this with 'openssl x509 -text -noout -in cert.pem'.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I want it so that all urls point to https://my.domain.org in any case so that everything is permanently redirected to that improving the google ranking of the url. I don't want to have multiple urls but I also don't want to stop people from using the old urls. It's not just a case of the certificate...

Comment: Sure - but you say your problem is "e browser gives the warning page for the certificate" ... " Any thoughts what's going wrong in my conditions". And the answer to that is that your certificate likely contains the wrong/incomplete information. So we need to fix that to get you what you want. The apache config itself is likely fine.

Comment: You are right my question was not very clear. I don't mind though the certificate erroring on this because I really want all the users to ever only go to one url so the real problem is redirecting the https alternative domain to the https domain I want. Thanks for you help!

Comment: So in that case - remove the first "RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on" as you in fact want to redirect for both HTTPS is on and off.